# Are PHAR archives secure?

Tags: php

I want to send the new releases of my application in encrypted, signed archives to the server. Are PHAR archives a good solution to do that? Is PHAR secure enough?

Comment: I do not think PHAR archives offer any encryption themselves, so it depends on how you configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796381/encryption-with-php-phar), it is not possible to encrypt the content of the archives. At least not with the current phar extension version (2.0) and not without a special compiler, for example [ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com/). Adding zip password causes an error by decompression, because the extension is not prepared to handle that. If you'd like encryption of the content for example for transport or storing purposes, I'd suggest another encryption layer on top of phar, for example SSL would do the job.

The signature seems to be okay, it is [based on a sha1 checksum of the phar archive](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/phar/util.c#1794) and a private key. So it protects the integrity of the package well. There are additional crc32 checksums stored in the manifests of the files, as another layer for data integrity protection... (Only the [crc32 would not be enough](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57723/is-it-possible-to-add-backdoor-to-a-file-with-the-same-size-and-crc32-checksum/57735).) So I don't think the archives can be faked without the private key.

Answer (score 2):

No, PHAR archives provide no security features in themselves. But you can sign updates using GPG like literally every other project does.

Some package management systems (rpm, deb, etc) allow for signature verification built-in. You can use one of those and get security for free, or you can implement it yourself.

Comment: and what about http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.signature.php ?

Comment: A signature without a key is just a hash. A malicious person could just regenerate the hash to cover the modifications. You need a key infrastructure or the whole exercise is pointless.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.setsignaturealgorithm.php

Comment: It should throw an exception by wrong signature, but I haven't tried yet, I am in the information collecting stage...

Comment: @inf3rno if you can tie the signature to a private key, then there's the possibility for security. But note that PHP does not require any software capable of verifying signatures to even be installed, so I'm not sure how solid the security actually is. Certainly the history of the PHP team does not fill me confidence on this matter.

Comment: by using phar signatures php requires openssl. As usual, the configuration of the server depends on you. So you can easily enforce php to verify package signatures if you want to.

Comment: If you have doubts about the security, then please check the source code: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/phar/util.c#1794 I am not an C nor a security expert, so sadly I cannot do that. Based on the documentation and tutorials it is secure enough.

Comment: No... I haven't even the slightest interest in doing a security audit of the PHP source code. Trust it if you feel so inclined.

Comment: In this case, this is just an opinion based on assumptions instead of any proof, so I cannot accept it. The phar extension provides digital signature with openssl, and digital signiture is not an atom reactor, so I think they implemented it well... Proof that I am wrong and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Do this: create an archive, sign it, install it. Test it. Then pretend to be a malicious user: modify the archive, sign it with a *different key*, and install your new version. If it works, then you've got problems.