# Is it possible to add backdoor to a file with the same size and crc32 checksum (4bytes)?

Tags: php, digital-signature

Is it possible to add backdoor to a file with the same size and crc32 checksum (4bytes)?

(The file does not contain byte code, it contains program code as text. The language is PHP.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** CRC-32 does not prevent deliberately creating a file with the same CRC-32 and size as another but with different contents. For that, you need a cryptographic hash, such as SHA-256.